# Simple Reminder Script doesn't work

Tags: powershell, scripting

Since, I am little forgetful, I am making a simple Powershell script, which will remind me of certain specified things at given time. Below is my code, which goes into infinite loops.

```
$whsehll = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.shell
$Reminder = Read-Host "What time do you want a reminder of?"
$Subject = Read-Host "What do you want me to remind you?"
$Time = Get-Date -Format hh:mm
do {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   }while (($Reminder -ge $Time)) 
   $whsehll.Popup("Hello, I am here to remind you of $Subject")
```

I have done all wayouts, but I am unable to work it out.

P.S. I ran a Get-date command first on powershell, and Got the time pattern as 03:00 instead 15:00hrs, so I assume that userinput should also be in 12 hrs clock pattern?

P.P.S. I did try other work-arounds like toggling with comparing options -gt -ge -lt -le but none of it works. Please help.

Comment: Kindly note that script, goes into infinite loops even if the specified time is elapsed.

Comment: Worked here for fine both `01:30` and  `1:30` (at time of `13:38`), when run inside ISE.

Comment: @Martin, that's great, it means my orignal code didn't have any problems but I am unsure, why this isn't working here with me. And, Yeah, so am Trying it on ISE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following

```
$Time = Get-Date -Format hh:mm
do {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```

to

```
do {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   $Time = Get-Date -Format hh:mm
```

and it will work.

You should take the **current** time each Loop, and not compare to the Initial time, when entered the loop.
Or use HH:mm for 24h format, as AgentK stated.

Note, that if $reminder ist 02:34, it will notify you at 02:35, because of `-ge` instead of -`gt` (or 14:34/35 when used HH:mm as Format).

For me it is easier to read/understand to just use a while Loop:

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.shell
$Reminder = Read-Host "What time do you want a reminder of?"
$Subject = Read-Host "What do you want me to remind you?"
while ($Reminder -gt (Get-Date -Format HH:mm)) 
{
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
$wshshell.Popup("Hello, I am here to remind you of $Subject")
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked, I wonder how did it work? See, we already declared the values at the start, where the reminder time wouldn't change and the time declaration which was passed, will get the time in hh:mm format only, right? I am sorry mate, I couldn't vote your answer since, reputation condition, but thanks for your answer it helped me to fix it. :)

Comment: No, just once, because it wasnt inside the loop. Ive edited a variant with using `while` instead of `do .. while`. Maybe its easier to read/use.

Comment: alright, one more thing, we have passed the parameter stating -ge which is >= but how come it shows only after completing the time, which will make default parameter as -gt rather than -ge. So, whats the point we/I using -ge?

Comment: If you set your reminder to 15:00 / 03:00, the Loop will be even entered if it is exactly 15:00 / 03:00. Your popup will Display at 15:01 / 03:01 because of `-ge (greater or equal)`. If you use `-gt` the Loop quits exactly at $reminder time and you will get your popup right in time.

Comment: ohkay, I got the logic now, Correct me if I am wrong, The script will always look out for every single condition is met or no. In the case $Reminder is at 3:00 and system time is 2:59. Now at 3:00 script will execute -eq and will find the time is equal to  $Reminder, but will not give a popup because it's still awaiting to complete the second condition which is "Greater than". where in the case of -gt it will only check one condition, finishing the job as soon as the mentioned time clicks.

Comment: Yes. Thats why i used simply `-gt` in my while example. -gt is just one comparator, like an abbreviation of  `-gt -or -eq`

Answer (score -2):

Fixed up your script a little and now it seems to be working:

```
$whsehll = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.shell
[datetime]$Reminder = Read-Host "What time do you want a reminder of?"
$Subject = Read-Host "What do you want me to remind you?"
$Time = Get-Date
do {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   }
while ($Reminder -ge $Time)
$whsehll.Popup("Hello, I am here to remind you of $Subject")
```

PS. If you using 24H format time you want to use capital H, like **HH:mm**

Comment: `Get-date -Format` produces a string, so the original posting alrady compares same datatypes (two strings).

Comment: @AgentK, I am sorry that didn't work either. I am sorry, but I didn't get the logic, cause, I think Get-date command will pull the entire date and time data, where as in I just want HH:MM

Comment: @Martin, Thanks for your input, but did you try the exact code I pasted in question and it worked for you? Or did you make any changes?

Comment: @Ashish I used exactly your code, and first thing Ive looked into were datatypes. Both $Reminder and $Time are Strings, so no Problem with a (char based) comparison. Sure, we could typecast to a number, but as `4 -ge 3` becomes $true, also `"4" -ge "3"` becomes $true.

Comment: Yep, well said, I second your opinion.